# How to know partitions' names

Tags: partitioning

How do I get to know partitions' names?

I entered `sudo fdisk -l`, and I got:

```
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1       156264318   273474494    58605088+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       273474558   353670974    40098208+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       390684798   507894974    58605088+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       507895038   625105214    58605088+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

For example, which one is DSK_VOL5 or DSK_VOL2?

Comment: mount -l output includes device labels for mounted devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `DSK_VOL5` and `DSK_VOL2` are your partition's label name. So run `sudo blkid` command, it will display all of your partitions along with the UUID and partition's label.

```
$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for avinash: 
/dev/sda1: UUID="2F4DAFCF02D7EBEB" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="fbfc57fa-7545-49f9-b1d0-812518de8597" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="C68C57908C5779BF" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="3EDAD310DAD2C2F7" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda7: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="B0AEE55CAEE51C1A" TYPE="ntfs"
```

In the above example, the label name given to my `/dev/sda7` partition is `New Volume`.

Comment: they call it partition label? I should say name or label which one is correct?

Comment: label is the correct one.